# How to stablish a one to many relationship between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relation

I'm dealing with this situation. I've got three tables in SQL SERVER called `Movies`, `Series` and `Orders`.

`Orders` has an `ItemId` where this could be a `MovieId` (Movies PK) or `SerieId` (Series PK). I mean, in Orders table could have records where are from movies of series.

I don't know how to maintain this relationship or which could be the best way to implement it. Until I know, I only can create 1 to 1 or 1 to many relationships between 2 tables, not for 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I personally always try design away from these situations, it becomes difficult to enforce keys, and you always end up having to decide the join to use on the fly. What is the rationale behind having movie and series split - can't they both be considered 'media' and you have a type field on that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I think it would be better to store Movies and Series in the same table with the common attributes incl. a column which indicates the type (Movie or Serie) and then have the additional attributes in seperate tables (if you want to normalize) or even in the same table (in order to avoid joins).

Comment: +1, store all common data in one single table, extend with additional tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about **implement [table inheritance](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server)** in sql-server.

Do you have a **product** and this product may be a **Movie** or a **Serie**.

In linked sample a **person** may be a **student** or a **teacher**.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

1. create a generic table for movies and series with the fields that both entities should share (like ItemId).
2. create a table for movies that references the table created on step 1, containing the fields that must be compiled only for movies. This new table will be in relation one-to-one with the previous one.
3. same thing for series.
4. create the orders table and set ItemId foreign key to point to the ItemId primary key of the table created on step 1.